# Nodejs Execution time script

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I run a simple script that calls a function and returns prints a result, in this way:

```
node --watch test.js
```

Is there any way to know how long it takes to execute the function.

I remember something that used a `--time` flag, but I'm not sure.

```js
let a = ...

function extract(input) {
 .....
}

const ext = extract(a);
console.log(ext);
```

There are other ways instead of using `console.time`:

```
console.time('test');
//some code
console.timeEnd('test'); //Prints something like that-> test: 11374.004ms
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: `time node test.js` in bash

Comment: What Konrad said, your measurements *within* node.js will be wrong because it will ignore the startup cost of the V8 JS engine.

Comment: @Konrad: But if it is used in combination with `--watch` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the built-in node.js library `perf_hooks`. The measurement goes like this:

```
import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks';
performance.mark('start');
// your code
performance.end('end');
const measure = performance.measure('measure fn', 'start', 'end');
const executionTime = measure.duration
```